Sanitizing with pg-format vs parametrized / prepared statements
Having come from an era where trends pushed away from sanitizing towards preparing parameters, I was surprised to see this library that seems to push back the other way - to sanitizing on the client. I definitely see advantages in this approach - you can log a fully prepared query on the client and moving the preparing from the db server to the client also has its advantages by taking this load off the db, and it claims to make queries totally safe when using the right formatting tokens.
What would be the disadvantages of using pg-format as opposed to prepared statements?
I understand from this answer that speed, when sending several similar queries, is one. Any others?

"moving the preparing from the db server to the client also has its advantages by taking this load off the db" - not sure what you think happens when preparing a statement, or how that compares to parsing load

"it claims to make queries totally safe when using the right formatting tokens" - that's a big "when". (There are other libraries that make this part a bit safer by not allowing string interpolation at all)

"by taking this load off the db" Well, using prepared statements are used to reduce the load, not the opposite. Reducing the need to plan query statements. Moving to, for example, pg-format, increases database load and the risk of SQL injection. Unless pg-format is perfect and has absolutely no bugs, not even unknown bugs.

Parameterized queries are safe, sanitized input less so. Queries needn't be explicitly prepared to be parameterized. Unless there is a significant efficiency gain that is worth the additional risk, don't trade safety for efficiency.

The main disadvantage you have when you sanitize your SQL statement by using your client library's query formatting functions is that you can make a mistake: either forget to sanitize something or use the wrong format code.

in pg-format you use the %L just like in prepared you would use ?. Isn't that the same chance of making a mistake?

You could use %s by accident and not be safe from SQL injection.

reassuring to hear from a postgres expert that this is the only concern :)
